# Jquery/Javascript - add a callback to my small function, apply that specific callback only when i choose to

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

When i launch the scrollMyScreen function, i want to be able to SOMETIMES call a callback(which i want to be my flashArrow function), which i thought would look something like: `scrollMyScreen(flashArrow())`, but obviously that doesn't work. my flashArrow function will actually be bigger than just an alert, this is just for example.

```
function scrollMyScreen() { 
    $('body').delay(600).animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 1000, callback)
}

function flashArrow () { 
    alert('FLASHING ARROW!')
};
```

So, what can I do to make this work? I want to call scrollMyScreen, and then sometimes add the function flashArrow() as it's callback, or, to happen once scrollMyScreen is done.

example case:

```
case "header": 
    scrollMyScreen()
    break
case "wrapper": 
    scrollMyScreen(flashArrow())
    break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a *reference* to `flashArrow`, not the *result* of calling `flashArrow()`:

```
case "header": 
    scrollMyScreen();
    break;
case "wrapper": 
    scrollMyScreen(flashArrow);   // change here
    break;
```

(and don't forget to declare the `callback` parameter to `scrollMyScreen()` too!)

Comment: thanks man, hey, could what i'm asking for also be accomplished if i turned scrollMyScreen and flashArrow into variables instead of functions?

Comment: A variable can only be "called" if it's value is a reference to a function.  So you still have to declare them just like you have now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var callback = null;

switch(something) {
    case "wrapper": 
        callback = flashArrow;
        break;
    case "somethingElse": 
        callback = flashSomethingElse;
        break;
}

scrollMyScreen(callback);



function scrollMyScreen(callback) { 
    $('body').delay(600).animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 1000, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function scrollMyScreen(callback) { 
$('body').delay(600).animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 1000, 
                              typeof(callback) == "function" ? callback : null);
}
```

You can then call:

```
scrollMyScreen(someFunction);
```

or:

```
scrollMyScreen();
```

**Update: Fixed callback null issue**

```
function scrollMyScreen(callback) { 
if (typeof(callback) == "function")
    $('body').delay(600).animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 1000, callback);
else
    $('body').delay(600).animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you explain why the `typeof(callback)...` part is needed? if i just have `scrollMyScreen();` it doesn't work, i need to add null: `scrollMyScreen(null);` in my code now i have a callback and a yoffset: `scrollMyScreen(yOffset, callback)`, i tried your code but it didn't keep me from having to add Null if i don't declare the callback or yoffset.

Comment: I fixed the problem. The typeof(callback) will return "function" if a function is passed and "undefined" if nothing is passed. The logic in scrollMyScreen ensures that the correct jQuery call is made based on the presence or absence of the callback parameter.